# JPA exception: Object: is not a known entity type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JPA and I'm having problems. I read that the problem maybe with the persistence.xml .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="GreekTravelPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>entities.Room</class>
<class>entities.Country</class>
<class>entities.User</class>
<class>entities.RoomType</class>
<class>entities.Role</class>
<class>entities.Photo</class>
<class>entities.Availability</class>
<class>entities.Message</class>
<class>entities.Location</class>
<class>entities.Booking</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"     value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/greektraveldb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="psilos"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="psilos"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My Exeption:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@665ba601 is not a known entity type.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3510)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.mergeCloneWithReferences(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:384)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.mergeCloneWithReferences(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3481)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.mergeInternal(EntityManagerImpl.java:542)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.merge(EntityManagerImpl.java:519)
```

The actual code is

```
@Override public void update(User user) { 
    EntityManager em = EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager(); 
    try { 
        EntityTransaction entityTrasacrion = em.getTransaction(); 
        entityTrasacrion.begin(); 
        em.merge(em); 
        entityTrasacrion.commit(); 
    } catch (RuntimeException e) { 
        throw e; 
    } finally { 
        EntityManagerHelper.closeEntityManager(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: We'll also need the code that causes the exception.

Comment: `@Override
    public void update(User user) {
        EntityManager em = EntityManagerHelper.getEntityManager();

        try {
            EntityTransaction entityTrasacrion = em.getTransaction();
            entityTrasacrion.begin();
            em.merge(em);
            entityTrasacrion.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            EntityManagerHelper.closeEntityManager();
        }
    }`

Comment: I want to update. Find in this link [link](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-update-entity-object-using-jpa/)

Comment: Have you tried this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657682/hibernate-4-3-6-and-glassfish-4-0-jpa-2-1-object-is-not-an-instance-of-declaring) ?

Comment: `manager.merge(artist);` - what's wrong with that?

Comment: Bad copy past.I find a second before @corsiKa answer.Realy sorry for the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're merging the entity manager with the entity manager!!! Ooops!

```
em.merge(em);
```

Needs to be

```
em.merge(user);
```